# Why is coffeescript interpreter rejecting 'for' token?

Tags: coffeescript

The coffeescript interpreter at coffeescript.org doesn't seem to like the 'for' keyword in any context in which I try to use it, reporting "unexpected terminator" when the 'r' is typed. Anyone have any idea what is going on? I've tried Safari and Chrome on my Mac. The following image shows the simplest example of the failure.

[image]

Edit: As noted in my comment on the accepted answer below, it turns out all of the 'for' examples I had tried were incomplete or (unbeknownst to me at the time) invalid.

Comment: Just `for` is not a valid statement so the compiler is supposed to raise an error. `for x in [1..5] --linebreak--
  alert(x)` is compiled as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enter a complete statement it will be OK, for instance:

```
for i in [1..3]
  alert i
```

`for` on its own is not valid CoffeeScript.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried what I thought was a valid and complete statement as well, but had mistakenly substituted "on" for "of" as my comprehension operator. I was thrown by the fact that the compiler output and error remained unchanged in that situation as well.